# SmartGWT: hide a column in a grouped grid (which makes the group)

Tags: smartgwt

I have a SmartGWT grid, where I want to display some data from JBoss-Server 
and it's grouped by one textfield that I fetch from JSON.

So, but I want this textfield only in the header of each group.

When I do .hideField on this field, then i'm loosing the group.

```
grid.hideField("pool");
```

But when i hide it over the context-menue of the grid header, the column remains.

Any idea how to do this?

Roman.

Comment: I would think it worked for me in the past but forget where (I think I removed from my code for GUI reason, but I remember I used the setHidden on the field when I defined it and not on the grid (pool.setHidden(true) . Can you try?

Answer (score 1):

There is simple and clean workaround. Just set **width** parameter of the filed to '0'. Additionally clear **title** parameter if you have one (but this is only necessary in some sophisticated ListGrid use cases).

Comment: setWidth(0) is clean?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had the most success [hiding the field using the DataSourceField](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSourceField.html#setHidden%28java.lang.Boolean%29) as opposed to the grid itself.

```
DataSource ds = new DataSource() {
    {
        DataSourceTextField field = new DataSourceTextField();
        field.setHidden(true);

        addField(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried in my datasource:

DataSourceTextField poolNameField = new DataSourceTextField("pool","Pool");
poolNameField.setHidden(true);
addField(poolNameField); 

getting Javascript exception:

groupBy() passed field:pool - this is not a valid field within this grid - ignoring

pool is the field I use to group my grid, thats the problem

Comment: again:

I tried in my datasource:

`DataSourceTextField poolNameField = new DataSourceTextField("pool","Pool");
poolNameField.setHidden(true);
addField(poolNameField);`

in windowcode:

`gridStats.setGroupByField("pool");`

getting Javascript exception:

**groupBy() passed field:pool - this is not a valid field within this grid - ignoring**

pool is the field I use to group my grid, thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

You've already posted   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834024/smartgwt-hide-a-column-in-a-grouped-grid-which-makes-the-group) and didn't answer to the people who oriented you toward the setHidden methode of the ListGridField.

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to hide the `ListGridField` like this:

```
    ListGridField groupField = new ListGridField(FLD_CATEGORY, "Group");
    groupField.setHidden(true);
```

Note that if you use a `DataSourceField`, you may need to declare hard-coded `ListGridField` definitions

Answer (score -1):

below tag will help to hide table column
listGrid.hideField("field_name");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).