# grouped gridlist hide column

Tags: smartgwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SmartGWT: hide a column in a grouped grid (which makes the group)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834024/smartgwt-hide-a-column-in-a-grouped-grid-which-makes-the-group)

I have a grouped grid in SmartGWT, and one column makes the group,
but i don't want to see this column, only the fields
as headers of the group it belongs to.

I tried .hideField, but this destroys my group...

But, when the code is running on the browser, i can manually
unselect the column under grid header context menu,
and the column disappears, but the group remains.

So, if it's working on the gui with a click, there must be a way to do it in my code?!

Thanks a lot!

Roman.